# How to use Spring REST HATEOAS from Angular?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-restcontroller, spring-hateoas

I was learning about Spring REST HATEOAS. But, I am confused about how we use it on the client end..

I mean, let's say I want write a client app using Angular JS. So now I don't have to hardcode the URL's to make REST API calls? And instead i'd use the "rel" attribute that gets returned?

for example, from angular JS,

- I'd use the root URL "/products"
- It returns links to individual products (Which I believe will be populated on UI)
- User selects a product and angular will fetch the product details, along with relevant links to that product to delete, edit, etc..
- If user clicks on delete, Angualar will use the URI specified in "rel=delete" to delete that product..

Is my understanding correct?
Is there a sample angular code, that doesn't hardcode URI but use the rel attribute?

Comment: Well you can use any client side API and extract the links from the json as required or use a more specialised client library such as https://github.com/2muchcoffeecom/ngx-restangular

Comment: Thanks! But, does client API get the URI based on 'rel=delete' attribute? If so, I assume the server side is expected to not change the 'rel' attribute as client will be hard coding it?